# Passing value from activity to view class

Tags: android, view, android-imageview

I have an activity in which there are 3 checkboxes in different views. These checkboxes are to pick up a color.

In the DrawingView class, I have to draw on my canvas with the color that is checked. What I want is to pass an integer value from the activity to the view class and set the color of paint accordingly.  itried using getter and setters, but I get black color. I suppose this is because the color is being set in the constructor itself, and it does not change when I check any box.

Please refer [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8516b2e7c364d90a250a6a92dc9b8361) for updates in the below code

Code:

**MainActivity**: the color/checkbox is selected here. And the drawing is to be done in the layout of this activity itself.

```
        carImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            drawingView=new DrawingView(carImageView.getContext());
            drawingView=new DrawingView(carImageView.getContext(),null);
            drawingView.setColor(color);
            return false;
        }
    });


  scratchesCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
          if(b)
          {
              color=1;
              chipsCb.setChecked(false);
              dentsCb.setChecked(false);
          }
      }
  });
    chipsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
            {
                color=2;
                scratchesCb.setChecked(false);
                dentsCb.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    dentsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
            {
                color=3;
                chipsCb.setChecked(false);
                scratchesCb.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**View Class:**

```
   public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
    mPaint=new Paint();
    if(color==1)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    else if(color==2)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    else if(color==3)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    this.context=context;
    mPath=new Path();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
}
     public void setColor(int color){
    this.color=color;
}
public int getColor(){
    return this.color;
}
```

### Edit

I don't necessarily want to use the exact same code. All I want is to change paint color when a checkbox is selected to be able to draw on an image view. Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: This setColor() will just update the variable color value but will not have any impact on the View because you never have invalidated the view with new color.

Comment: in the same method ?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you make a gist of your DrawingView class and share link in comment ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16140c59c001f22c2ffbf78f4dcfd488

Comment: For me it is changing the color.Though it does not preserve previous state, that's a different issue anyway.

Comment: The same code? I'm getting black lines only. Tried debugging, the checkbox value is being passed to the setColor method in the drawingview class, but its 0 somehow. Please extend some help.

Comment: of course same line of code, only thing I changed is removing invalidate call inside setColor method, because it was not rquired anyway

Comment: It isn't working for me.

Comment: I am doing nothing fancy but just this: https://gist.github.com/TheLittleNaruto/5ddb4d11400e059902976a8a42356814 ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MainActivity, you are creating a `DrawingView` that has no relationship to your image view that is displayed. So, when you change the color, you are not changing the color of the displayed image view but of the unconnected `DrawingView`. The image view never has a new color defined and always defaults to black.

Here is a video of a small working app based upon your most recently supplied code. Maybe all the colors shouldn't change when a new check box is clicked, but you will be able to address that issue separately.

Changes I have made to the Java code are commented as such. Changes were also made to the XML to allow your code to run in my environment, but those changes were not commented.

[image]

**MainActivity.java (Updated)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView caricon;
    int itemSelected = 0;
    private DrawingView carImageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView backarrow;
    TextView nextcheckinAB2;
    Bitmap bmp;
    public static int color;
    CheckBox scratchesCb, chipsCb, dentsCb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        carImageView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.carImageView);
        scratchesCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.scratchesCheckBox);
        chipsCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ChipCheckbx);
        dentsCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.DentsCheckBox);

        // Change: Make sure to initialize the color
        color = 1;
        carImageView.setColor(color);

        carImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                // drawingView = new DrawingView(carImageView.getContext(),null);
                carImageView.setColor(color);
                return false;
            }
        });


        scratchesCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    color = 1;
                    carImageView.clearCanvas();
                    carImageView.setColor(1); //
                    chipsCb.setChecked(false);
                    dentsCb.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        chipsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    color = 2;
                    carImageView.setColor(2);
                    scratchesCb.setChecked(false);
                    dentsCb.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
        dentsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    color = 3;
                    // Change: Do like the other check boxes althogh not really needed.
                    carImageView.setColor(3);
                    chipsCb.setChecked(false);
                    scratchesCb.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**DrawingView.java (Updated)**

```
public class DrawingView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
    int color;
    Context context;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();


    }

    public void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        if (color == 1) {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            this.color = color;
            invalidate();
        } else if (color == 2) {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            this.color = color;
            invalidate();
        } else if (color == 3) {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            this.color = color;
            invalidate();
        }

    }

    public int getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    private void onStartTouch(float x, float y) {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (mX + x) / 2, (mY + y) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvas() {
        mPath.reset();
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        invalidate();
    }

    private void upTouch() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                onStartTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upTouch();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml (Updated)**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalSrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                                android:text="Scratches"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/scratchesCheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:checked="true" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                                android:text="Chips"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/ChipCheckbx"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                                android:text="Dings/Dents"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/DentsCheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8.7">

        <[your package name].DrawingView
            android:id="@+id/carImageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <!--<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did the exact same thing, still getting black lines.

Comment: @Harshita The code above does work. Are you still creating the `DrawingView` in MainActivity? Can you post the latest iteration of your code with the changes suggested above that still has the black lines including the XML?

Comment: Yes, One minute please

Comment: I haven't added all of the code as its very long. But added everything relevant to this question. In case anything is missing, please let me know.https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0427f35c566d6a167497352a5002e13

Comment: @Harshita I see the new code you posted. That code will not run due to errors. For instance, `carImageView` needs to be final to be referenced in the anonymous class. You also have the `onTouch()` listeners buried in the listener for `carImageView` where they don't belong. It would help if you can post code that will 1) compile and run and 2) exhibit the bad behavior you are trying to resolve. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have identified the issue. We just need to get it translated to your code so that it works.

Comment: should I create a new gist and paste the entire code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8516b2e7c364d90a250a6a92dc9b8361  I've put a working code, without drawables or anything. i am not too experienced, so please help/ cooperate accordingly. Also please tell if this is not the right way to share.

Comment: Should I expect your reply or no?

Comment: @Harshita See updated answer. The code I have posted works as you can see in the posted video. I suggest that you get this code working in your environment and introduce other code you may have bit-by-bit until you find the problem. The only thing I have not looked at is how you reset the canvas and load images for the car image view. It is possible that you are trouncing the color when you do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160152/discussion-between-harshita-and-cheticamp).

Answer (score 1):

you need change function setColor.

1.change mPaint color.

2.add invalidate() for redraw view.

```
public void setColor(int color){
    this.color=color;
     mPaint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `invalidate()` on the `View` to make it update.

Try this,

```
final DrawingView drawingView = new DrawingView(carImageView.getContext());

carImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        drawingView.setColor(color);
        return false;
    }
});


scratchesCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
      if(b)
      {
          color = 1;
          drawingView.setColor(color);

          chipsCb.setChecked(false);
          dentsCb.setChecked(false);
      }
  }
});

chipsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(b)
        {
            color = 2;
            drawingView.setColor(color);

            scratchesCb.setChecked(false);
            dentsCb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});


dentsCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(b)
        {
            color = 3;
            drawingView.setColor(color);

            chipsCb.setChecked(false);
            scratchesCb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

DrawingView.java

```
public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mPath=new Path();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    setColor(color);
}


public void setColor(int color){
    this.color=color;
    if(color==1)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    else if(color==2)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    else if(color==3)
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    // Call invalidate
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting black only.

Comment: even if I pass a static value, say 3 in main activity in drawingview.setColor(int) it gives black. This means the setcolor function in Drawingview isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

"even if I pass a static value, say 3 in main activity in `drawingview.setColor(int)` it gives black. This means the `setColor` function in Drawingview isn't working. "

Does this mean it will call `paint.setColor(3)` ?

If yes, this will of course turn your color black. Try passing `Color.GREEN` instead

Answer (score 0):

Define static data member in your DrawingView

static int color = 1; //default

Then, from your activity simply call

DrawingView.color = someValue;

Static Keyword before variable color will make sure there is only one variable reference for all objects of your DrawingView class.